# WP e-Commerce Canada Post shipping module

Tags: wordpress

I need the plugin for the canada post shipping. I have found [this module.](http://blog.yannbouschet.com/module-expedition-poste-canada-pour-wp-e-commerce/) When i tried to upload the upload and activacte the plugin i got an error "The plugin does not have a valid header."

The wp_version = '3.0.1'; is the version i am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the main file for the addon.  It will have something like this at the top:

```
/* Plugin Name: {Name of plugin}
...
```

The error that you are getting means that the plugin header (the stuff at the top of that file) is not setup correctly so WordPress can read the information it needs about the plugin.  It could be that there are incorrect line breaks in the file or it's encoded in a weird way (which happens if it's been modified in anyway or not ftp'd correctly)

You can go [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information) to find out what it should look like at the top of that file.

Comment: Mark this answer as complete first.  And then post your other question as a separate question.